# Traceback (most recent call last): (works in trinket.io but not 3.4/2.7.11)

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, exception

```
    # start of number game.
import random

guessesTaken = 0
guessesLeft =  6

def numberGuess():
    guessesTaken = 0
    guessesLeft =  6
    number = random.randint(1, 10)
    print('I am thinking of a number between 1 and 10.' + "\n"  + 'Can you guess the number?')
    print('You have 6 guesses.')

while guessesTaken < 6:
    guess = input("Your guess:")

    try:
        guess = int(guess)
    except ValueError:
        print("That's not a number stupid")

    guessesTaken = guessesTaken + 1
    guessesLeft = guessesLeft - 1

    if guess < number:
        print('Your guess is too low.') 

    if guess > number and guess <= 10:
        print('Your guess is too high.')

    if guess > 10:
        print('Please use a number 1-10.')

    if guessesLeft <= 5 and guessesLeft != 0 and guess != number:
        print ('You have ' +  str(guessesLeft) + ' guesses left.')

    if guess == number:
        break

if guess == number:
    guessesTaken = str(guessesTaken)
    print('Good job! You guessed my number in ' + guessesTaken + ' guesses!' + "\n" + "\n" + 'Lets play again!')
    numberGuess()

if guess != number:
    number = str(number)
    print('Nope. ' + number + ' was the number I was thinking of.' + "\n" + "\n" + 'Lets play again!')
    numberGuess()
```

numberGuess()

So basically it works perfectly fine in trinket.io (which you can see here; http://sobieski.codes/guess/ )
but for some reason if I run in it idle IDE or my Ubuntu server (running 3.4) I get this error.

```
Your guess:a
That's not a number stupid
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "loopgame.py", line 49, in <module>
    numberGuess()
  File "loopgame.py", line 48, in numberGuess
    numberGuess()
  File "loopgame.py", line 43, in numberGuess
    numberGuess()
  File "loopgame.py", line 25, in numberGuess
    if guess < number:
TypeError: unorderable types: str() < int()
```

Which as you can see, it correctly determines that its NOT a number, but still gives me a traceback, can you help me understand why?

```
NameError: name 'a' is not defined
```

IDLE ide error.

Answer (score 0):

I think compare a `string` and `int` raises a `TypeError` in python 3.4 not a `ValueError` , however in python 2.7 it raises a `ValueError` ,  you should add multiple `try except` part for handle these exceptions.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but still comes back with not defined (actually doesn't work in any of the 3) what doesn't make sense to me is it works in trinket.io which is also running a modified version of 3.* but it IS somewhere within that except snippet. I'll keep looking through that link though as there is much I didn't know, so thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Didn't finish handling the except, just needed to add the continue so it knew to carry on after it caught and printed the error. The IDLE ide was because 2.7 and 3.5 don't mix well, upgraded idle ide to 3.5 and it plays just fine.